# Find $\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sinh x}{1+\cosh^2 x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sinh x}{1+\cosh^2 x}dx$$

I used the substitution $u=\cosh x$ to simplify the integral to:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+u^2}du$$

Are the limits still correct? Then substituting $u=\tan y$:

$$\int_{\tan^{-1}(1)}^{\tan^{-1}(\infty)}dy$$

Is this correct? How do I go about evaluating $\tan^{-1}\infty$?

Comment: You are simply supposed to *know* that it is $\pi/2$

Comment: The integral as a whole or the value of $\tan^{-1}\infty$?

Comment: Well you made a mistake. Cosh(0)=1. Your bounds are wrong

Comment: Any other errors? I will make an edit now

Comment: You are supposed to know that $\int \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx = \arctan x$ and thus $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+x^2}dx = \arctan(\infty) - \arctan(0) = \frac{\pi}{2}$, to complete  grdgfgr's comment.

Comment: So the lower limit is zero?

Comment: No it is $1$, the answer turns out to be $\pi/4$.

Comment: At what point have I gone wrong? Could someone please post an answer?

Comment: Since $\tan(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}$ and knowing that $\cos(\frac{\pi}{2}) = 0$ leads to $\tan(\frac{\pi}{2}) = \frac{1}{0} = \infty$. Inversion leads to $\tan^{-1}(\infty) = \frac{\pi}{2}$. Similarly one can determine that $\tan^{-1}(1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$. As to the integral the evaluation is $\tan^{-1}(\infty) - \tan^{-1}(1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$.

Comment: You were wrong during the change of variable. If $y = \phi(x)$ (in your case $y = \mathrm{acosh}(x)$) then $\int_a^b f(x)dx = \int_{\phi^{-1}(a)}^{\phi^{-1}(b)} f(\phi(x)) |\phi'(x)|dx$. Thus in your case you should have, if $f(x) = \frac{\sinh(x)}{1+\cosh^2(x)}$, $\int_{\cosh(0)}^{\cosh(\infty)} f(\mathrm{acosh}(x)) |\mathrm{acosh}'(x)|dx$. Then evaluate the integral as in my previous comment, replacing 0 by 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct up through here:

$$\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+u^2}du$$

Since the antiderivative of $\frac1{1+u^2}$ is $\arctan u$, the next step is to simply evaluate the integral:

$$=\arctan(\infty) - \arctan 1$$

It helps to just keep this image in mind for computing $\theta = \arctan x$, taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_trigonometric_functions):

[image]

For $\arctan 1$, that's an isosceles right triangle, so $\frac{\pi}4$. For $\arctan \infty$, you can see that it's $\frac{\pi}2$. Hence:

$$=\frac{\pi}2 - \frac{\pi}4$$
$$=\frac{\pi}4$$